# Is the poset of natural numbers cofiltered?

Tags: category-theory

Consider the category $\mathbb{N}_{\geq}$ whose objects lie in $\mathbb{N}$, and there is a single morphism $n \rightarrow m$ if $n \leq m$, and otherwise there is no morphism between $n$ and $m$.

A category $C$ is called cofiltered if:

- It is non-empty.
- For every $i, j \in Ob(C)$ there is $k \in Ob(C)$ with morphisms $k \rightarrow i$, $k \rightarrow j$.
- For every $i, j \in Ob(C)$ and pair of morphisms $f_1, f_2: i \rightarrow j$, there is $k \in Ob(C)$ and a morphism $g: k \rightarrow i$ such that $f_1 \circ g 
   = f_2 \circ g$.

Is $\mathbb{N}_{\geq}$ cofiltered? I believe it is, since it is clearly non-empty, and for any $i$, $j \in Ob(C)$ we can just take the lesser of the two which automatically gives unique morphisms to each. For the third requirement we can just do the same again and take the identity morphism on the lesser of $i$ and $j$ since there is only one morphism between each.

A category $C$ is filtered if $C^{\text{op}}$ is cofiltered. I believe $C$ is also filtered by similar reasoning. Can anyone confirm or contradict my claims? My main motivation for asking is that my textbook uses $\mathbb{N}_{\geq}$ as an example of a filtered category and $\mathbb{N}_{\geq}^{\text{op}}$ as an example of a cofiltered category, but I believe both fill both requirements. Is this just a badly written example or am I making a mistake?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just pointing out a small typo, you say "A category $C$ is filtered if $C^\text{op}$ is filtered." One of those "filtered" should be "cofiltered".

Comment: Maybe a better example for a filtered category is take the poset $\mathcal{P}_{fin}(\mathbb{N})$ of all finite subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ (or any infinite set), ordered by inclusion. This forms a filtered category, but it is not a cofiltered category. Dually, of course, we then have that $\mathcal{P}_{fin}^\text{op}(\mathbb{N})$ is cofiltered but not filtered.

Comment: A different but equivalent definition of filtered category that I like and I think makes it a bit clearer what's going on is: $\mathcal C$ is filtered if for every *finite* diagram in $\mathcal C$ admits a cocone in $\mathcal C$. For cofiltered, it's a cone. This is a categorification of the notion of a [directed set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_set) which states every finite subset of a poset has an upper bound. For your example, this becomes a question of whether any finite set of naturals has both an upper and lower bound in the naturals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, this poset is both filtered and cofiltered. It's a rather degenerate example of a cofiltered poset, though, as it has a least element, or in categorical language an initial object. We are often interested in filtered colimits and cofiltered limits, but the limit of a diagram indexed by a category admitting an initial object is given trivially, by evaluation at that object.